# Bind SSH port forwarding to IP by user

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to bind a specific user to a certain IP when using port forwarding (preferably dynamic) in SSH? I don't mind if it has to be done by the user, but by the server configuration would be preferred.

Basically what's happening is I have multiple addresses on the machine, one is the default eth0 (let's say 192.168.1.100) and another is eth0:1 (192.168.1.101). When I open a dynamic tunnel (`ssh -D 1080 192.168.1.100`) from a remote machine, I'd like all my traffic to appear as if it's coming from `.101` instead of the default `.100`.

Is there any way of doing this short of going with a solution that binds an entire user to an IP? Or, potentially, configuring a local SOCKS application and just local forwarding to that port instead?

Comment: I have needed to do this once, and now I need it again. Sadly, I don't remember exactly how I did it. But I'm quite sure it involved `iptables`. Update: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port

Answer (score -1):

These links might help?

http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/linux/redhat/bind_multiple_ip_addresses_to_single_nic/index.php

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bind-alias-range-of-ip-address-in-linux/

Comment: The OP is asking how to force SSH traffic with a specific source address per-user, not how to add more IPs to his NIC. He already has that.